# Android master detail guidelines

Tags: android, android-layout

How wide should be "master" section on android? In examples they usually create master section with weight=1 and height with weight=2, so master is 1/3 of height. Is it good for real-world app?

And also, how does usually master-detail layout behave in portrait orientation, in examples sections become narrow. Is this good too, or should I hide master section like on iPad?

Comment: in master-detail layout master usually is kind of list of items and detail name speaks for itself

Comment: 1/3 - 2/3 is good, but for very large screens it may look like a lot of space for the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android UI guidelines provides variety of UI patterns for master-detail layout, there is no one general solution.